# Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction

Tags: equilibrium, experimental-chemistry

The Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction is a very fascinating one. The Chemistry behind the reaction concerns thermodynamics and equilibrium. I want to perform the experiment, but I'm not able to find detailed instructions about the reaction. Like, proportions of the chemicals, explanation of the reaction, duration of the reaction, sequence of mixing the reagents, etc.

The [Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBa4kgXI4Cg) is a video I found on YouTube.

But that does not give any details at all. Can anyone give me a detailed reaction procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is indeed a fascinating reaction!  The following is a part answer, providing links to some resources that may be of use.

The following resources may be of assistance:

The [Belousov-Zhabotinsky](http://linus.chem.ku.edu/genchemlab/1892008/Click%20Here%20for%20BZ%20Reaction%20Info.htm) page from the Kansas Academy for Mathematics and Science Education provides a bit about the background, chemical processes and most relevant to your request, an experimental procedure.

Mary Newton of the Georgia Regent University has provided a reasonably detailed procedure on the webpage [Procedure for B-Z reaction](http://www.aug.edu/nonlinear/bz.htm).

Slightly different, is the information provided in the [Belousov-Zhabotinsky Reaction](http://home2.fvcc.edu/~dhicketh/DiffEqns/spring05projects/ErikLeigh/BZ.htm) (Leigh) page from the Flathead Valley Community College takes a different approach, with a focus on the mathematical derivations relevant to the experiment.